# MySQL - Jointure with OR condition in 2 bloc with AND condition

Tags: mysql

This query works fine with most server but does not work well with some other. It cause CPU overload or empty result.

```
SELECT 
    M.id,
    M.sender,
    M.recipient,
    M.date,
    M.read,
    U.ID
FROM
    msg M,
    users U
WHERE 
    (M.recipient='".$user_login."' and 
    M.deleted!=1 and
    U.user_login=M.sender)
    or
    (M.sender='".$user_login."' and 
    M.deleted!=2 and
    U.user_login=M.recipient)
ORDER BY M.date DESC
```

I have change to this but same issue :

```
SELECT 
    M.id,
    M.sender,
    M.recipient,
    M.date,
    M.read,
    U.ID
FROM
    msg M
LEFT JOIN
    users U
ON
    (M.recipient='".$user_login."' and 
    M.deleted!=1 and
    U.user_login=M.sender)
    or
    (M.sender='".$user_login."' and 
    M.deleted!=2 and
    U.user_login=M.recipient)
ORDER BY M.date DESC
```

I think the problem is the jointure clause with 2 cases.

I don't think there can be a case problem with "id" and "ID".

Of course I can make 2 queries but surely there is a way to do this with a single query.

Comment: Can you post the result of EXPLAIN the query?

Comment: No, sorry. This is a part of a WordPress plugin and users report this issue but don't know how to get more debug informations.

Comment: just execute EXPLAIN SELECT M.id, M.sender ...... in your database and paste the result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OR in a JOIN condition sounds like a horrible idea. Normally a UNION would be the better solution:-

```
SELECT 
    M.id,
    M.sender,
    M.recipient,
    M.date AS msg_date,
    M.read,
    U.ID
FROM msg M
INNER JOIN users U
ON U.user_login=M.sender
WHERE M.recipient='".$user_login."'
AND M.deleted!=1
UNION
SELECT 
    M.id,
    M.sender,
    M.recipient,
    M.date AS msg_date,
    M.read,
    U.ID
FROM msg M
INNER JOIN users U
ON U.user_login=M.recipient
WHERE M.sender='".$user_login."'  
AND M.deleted!=2 
ORDER BY msg_date DESC
```

Comment: Gives empty result. Works fine without ORDER but need to be ordered after.

Comment: @Jacques - Modified it (I had left the table alias in the order clause). Try it now.